# How to remove white lines from top of HTML table cells in email signature when it renders in Outlook?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I've designed an email signature using PNG image slices that fit together perfectly without any margins, and I'm using an HTML table to assemble it. It looks great in Gmail and renders correctly in webmail:

[image: Email signature as seen in Gmail]

However, Outlook adds some weird padding to the top of each cell, overlapping the PNG and leaving fairly thick (~15px) white lines over the signature:

[image: Email signature in Outlook]

I've introduced loads of extra attributes to the code to try to solve it, including defining `width` and `height` (some relative and some absolute) values for both the `img` and `td` tags, setting `margin` and `padding` to `0` in all directions, setting `cellpadding` to `0`, setting `line-height` to `0`, using `border-collapse`, and adding `mso-table-tspace` and `mso-table-top` `0` values with inline CSS, all to no avail. I've scoured the web for similar-sounding problems, but all of the solutions for those have failed for me.

Bizarrely, when I paste the signature from Chrome directly into an Outlook compose window, there is the same problem but the lines aren't as thick:

[image: email signature]

Here's my code:

```
<style>
    table, td {
        mso-table-tspace: 0pt !important;
        mso-table-top: 0pt !important;
    }
</style>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="365" height="205" style="background: none; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; width:365px; height:205px; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td width="365" height="105" style="line-height:0; width:365px; height:105px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <a href="https://www.caveen.com/"><img border="0" style="display: inline" src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_01.png" style="margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; width: 100%; max-width: 365px; height: 100%; max-height: 105px;" width="365" height="105" alt="Samuel M. Caveen | Digital Communications Specialist | Strategy, Copy and Design"/></a>&nbsp;</td>
      <br>
      <tr>
          <td width="365" height="20" style="line-height:0; width:365px; height:20px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">
          <img style="display: inline;line-height: 50%" src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_02.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 365px; height: 100%; max-height: 20px;" width="365" height="20"></td>
          </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
          <td width="365" height="26" style="line-height:0; width:365px; height:26px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_03.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 17px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="17" height="26"><a href="https://www.caveen.com/"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_04.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 111px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="111" height="26"></a><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_05.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 237px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="237" height="26"></td>
     </tr>
            <br>
            <td width="365" height="9" style="line-height:0; width:365px; height:9px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_06.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 365px; height: 100%; max-height: 9px;" width="365" height="9"></td>
          </tr>
      <br>
      <tr>
          <td width="365" height="26" style="line-height:0; width:365px; height:26px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_07.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 17px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="17" height="26"><a href="tel:+447980066496"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_08.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 163px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="163" height="26"></a><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_09.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 19px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="19" height="26"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/caveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_10.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 23px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="23" height="26"></a><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_11.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 9px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="9" height="26"><a href="https://www.twitter.com/SamCaveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_12.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 23px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="23" height="26"></a><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_13.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 8px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="8" height="26"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/caveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_14.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 24px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="24" height="26"></a><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_15.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 8px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="8" height="26"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrhGVjr4HA6mlinwoMFAk_g"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_16.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 24px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="24" height="26"></a><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_17.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 8px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="8" height="26"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/samcaveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_18.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 23px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="23" height="26"></a><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_19.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 16px; height: 100%; max-height: 26px;" width="16" height="26">
</tr>
                          <br>
            <td width="365" height="19" style="line-height:0; width:365px; height:19px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_20.png" style="width: 100%; max-width: 365px; height: 100%; max-height: 19px;" width="365" height="19">
          </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not a developer but I have a fairly solid grasp of HTML/CSS, so I don't think there are any amateur mistakes here. I've just been going over this to fix it for Outlook without success.

Comment: try display block instead of display inline. Display block is recommended by lots of people and email devs. Also remove width and height on td's. The height and width will be dependent on the child element

Answer (score 2):

I found some mistakes:

1. Opening/closing tags - Found quite a few opening or closing tags missing. Mostly table rows.
2. Line break tags (<‌br />) in-between table rows - This isn't valid HTML. You should be using padding on table cells to add any spacing. Although you don't actually seem to need spacing so the line breaks are redundant.
3. The use of display:inline - You should be using display:block; on standalone images and any images sitting side by side, should be using display:inline-block.
4. Heights on images - Remove the heights from your images. This may not have been the exact cause and I can't double check as I made this change before I made the biggest change. But overall, unless the height is being used for spacing and sizing, there really isn't any need.
5. Line heights - Don't use zero line-heights. This is what was causing the random spacing. If you are going to use line heights, use the intended image height as the line height, in conjunction with height.
6. Image borders - Add either border="0" as an attribute or border:none; in the style tag on all images.
7. Use nested tables - When placing elements side by side, it's always recommended that you use nested tables. For instance, the row with I think 13 images side by side, you could wrap those in another table and separate each image into table cells. This allows the table to hand hold the elements for you and stop images wrapping, an issue I'm seeing in 120 DPI Outlook tests and on email clients other than Outlook, especially on mobile.

Take a look at my fixes and you'll see my points. I would suggest breaking all side by side images into table cells and you should see a massive improvement in your tests.
*I had to add head and body tags to be able to test this in Litmus. So feel free to remove to follow your normal process.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    table, td {
      mso-table-tspace: 0pt !important;
      mso-table-top: 0pt !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="365" height="205" style="background: none; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; width:365px; height:205px; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
      <td width="365" height="105" style="line-height:105px; width:365px; height:105px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <a href="https://www.caveen.com/"><img border="0" src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_01.png" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 365px;" width="365" border="0" alt="Samuel M. Caveen | Digital Communications Specialist | Strategy, Copy and Design"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="365" height="20" style="line-height:20px; width:365px; height:20px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">
        <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_02.png" style="display: block; line-height: 50%; width: 100%; max-width: 365px;" width="365" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="365" height="26" style="line-height:26px; width:365px; height:26px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_03.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 17px;;" width="17" border="0" />
          <a href="https://www.caveen.com/"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_04.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 111px;" width="111" border="0" /></a>
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_05.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 237px;" width="237" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="365" height="9" style="line-height:9px; width:365px; height:9px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_06.png" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 365px;" width="365" border="0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="365" height="26" style="line-height:26px; width:365px; height:26px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;">
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_07.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 17px;" width="17" border="0" />
          <a href="tel:+447980066496"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_08.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 163px;" width="163" border="0" /></a>
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_09.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 19px;" width="19" border="0" />
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/caveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_10.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 23px;" width="23" border="0" /></a>
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_11.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 9px;" width="9" border="0" />
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/SamCaveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_12.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 23px;" width="23" border="0" /></a>
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_13.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 8px;" width="8" border="0" />
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/caveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_14.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 24px;" width="24" border="0" /></a>
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_15.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 8px;" width="8" border="0" />
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrhGVjr4HA6mlinwoMFAk_g"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_16.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 24px;" width="24" border="0" /></a>
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_17.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 8px;" width="8" border="0" />
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/samcaveen"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_18.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 23px;" width="23" border="0" /></a>
          <img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_19.png" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; max-width: 16px;" width="16" border="0" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="365" height="19" style="line-height:19px; width:365px; height:19px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;"><img src="https://www.caveen.com/s/Email-signature_20.png" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 365px;" width="365" border="0" />
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```